# How can I identify coverage types in NFL games using Computer vision

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, dataset, computer-vision

I am currently working on a project that classifies coverage types from sports highlights using advanced computer vision techniques. Next Gen Stats effectively utilizes tracking data to identify coverage zones during plays, and my goal is to achieve similar results directly from highlights.

I collected relevant data from various matches and extracted specific plays with distinct coverage zones to accomplish this. Subsequently, I applied this dataset to train a video classification model. Despite my efforts, I have encountered challenges in obtaining the desired results, and I am actively exploring ways to enhance the model's performance for more accurate coverage type identification.

I seek advice on optimizing the data collection process and improving the model's efficacy. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what techniques you've used so far? Right now your question is very open-ended. Interesting challenge however!